# Android - java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I'm getting a FATAL EXCEPTION: main when I run the app. It run first but for a few seconds it crash.

Here is my Logcat :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not read input channel file descriptors from parcel.
                                                 at android.view.InputChannel.nativeReadFromParcel(Native Method)
                                                 at android.view.InputChannel.readFromParcel(InputChannel.java:148)
                                                 at android.view.IWindowSession$Stub$Proxy.addToDisplay(IWindowSession.java:752)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:527)
                                                 at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
                                                 at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
                                                 at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
                                                 at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:993)
                                                 at com.mobext.shakeys.ActivityMain$ProcessData.onPostExecute(ActivityMain.java:545)
                                                 at com.mobext.shakeys.ActivityMain$ProcessData.onPostExecute(ActivityMain.java:212)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
                                                 at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Inside my ActivityMain.java:542 in alrt.show() this is where the logcat point it:

```
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        Log.i(TAG, "onPostExecute");
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        if(result){

            Log.i(TAG, "TASK IS DONE");
            try {
                PackageInfo pInfo = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0);
                app.saveToLastPref(ActivityMain.this, app.PREFS_PREV_VERSION, pInfo.versionName);
            } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ActivityMenuPage.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();
        }else{
            ActivityMain.this.deleteDatabase("DBSHAKEYS");
            Builder alrt = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);
            alrt.setMessage("Update failed. Please check your internet connection and try again.");
            alrt.setPositiveButton("Okay", new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            alrt.show();
        }
    }

}
```

And in ActivityMain.java:212 :

```
public class ProcessData extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>
```

Comment: You may have some `AlertDialog` already showing before `alrt.show()` method is called. Have you checked that properly ? is Builder your custom class ?

Answer (score 0):

I think `Builder` is your custom class that you are using now to show the `AlertDialog`.

**Here is what may happened**

The `onPostExecute()` method was called automatically after your some background process was finished executing. And then It tried to use the Builder class which may be currently being used by another process and still running in the memory.

**How can it be solved then ?**

1. Review your code and see if the dialog is already being shown using
   Builder class.
2. Simply change this line 
   `Builder alrt = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);` to normally `AlertDialog.Builder alrt = new AlertDialog.Builder(mcontext);`
   and see if this works.

Comment: @RussVirtuoso what is your mContext ? is this your Activity like `MyActivity.this` or something else ?

Comment: @RussVirtuoso simply debug your app putting `AlertDialog.Builder alrt = new AlertDialog.Builder(MyActivity.this);`. and this should work.